# Java JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I'm trying to add a Vertical scrolling my java programs textarea. I am using this code to create my JScrollPane:

console = my textarea.

I am also Declaring JScrollPane vertical;

```
        vertical = new JScrollPane(console);
    vertical.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    vertical.setVisible(true);
    this.add(vertical);
```

**EDIT:**

View of program:

[image]
I'm new to Java but shouldn't that work and add a Vertical scroll bar to my textarea

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you adding 'vertical' to anything? :)

Comment: Yea, adding it to the JPanel "this.add(vertical);"

Comment: Looks correct... Could you upload some screenshot of what you are actually getting?

Comment: @fortran Updated Original post with picture.

Comment: Don't you have to do it the other way around? Add the text area to the scroll pane.

Comment: @BenvanGompel How would I do that?

Comment: Oh, wait, I think that's already what you are doing. I must have misread your question. I'll think about it some more.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).
  BTW - it seems very strange that the "Load" & "Save" buttons are not aligned.  I suspect that is a symptom of the problem.

Comment: @AndrewThompson they aren't aligned because I haven't gotten around to finishing them perfectly. and

Comment: And what?  And where is your SSCCE?

Comment: See also [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an example:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ScrolledPane extends JPanel
{
    private JScrollPane vertical;
    private JTextArea console;

    public ScrolledPane()
    {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 250));
        console = new JTextArea(15, 15);

        vertical = new JScrollPane(console);
        vertical.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        add(vertical);
    }


    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        new JFrame()
        {{
            getContentPane().add(new ScrolledPane());
            pack();
            setVisible(true);
        }};
    }
}
```

Comment: please amend that new JTextArea(int, int);, then is definitions for PreferredSize use-less +1

Comment: Thanks for the great example it works now, but for some reason it is always in the middle of the window, shown here - http://screensnapr.com/v/LnRvql.png is there any way I can set a custom location?

Answer (score 8):

I think that in official tutorial about [JTextArea](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) and [JScrollPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) is described everything about that, another examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/0800__JScrollPane.htm) and [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/0280__JTextArea.htm)

```
mySchroll = new JScrollPane(myTextArea, 
    ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
    ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Demo extends JFrame {

    private JTextArea textArea;
    private JScrollPane scroll;

    Demo(){
        super("Write here...");
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(22); /*22 is a const value for always vertical */
        add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setSize(270,270);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Demo();
    }



}
```

*Output of the code :*
[See](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUJIr.png)