# how to add data in scrollpane?

Tags: javafx, scrollpane

```
bsave.setOnAction( e -> savecontacts());

private void savecontacts(){

    Name.getText();
    PhoneNumber.getText();
    Address.getText();
    System.out.println("Save");
}

Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 500, Color.WHITE);
ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
sp.setPrefSize(280, 280);
sp.setContent(rect);
```

In event handling .. I am getting data from textFeilds to save data. Now I have to Show this data in Scrollpane.How I will show?

Comment: Oracle's documentation: [Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: [Simple example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766844/java-jscrollpane?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a `TableView`, which allows you to display several columns of data based on item data. (`ListView` being an alternative for a single "column" without a header.) It automatically adds a `ScrollBar`, if the number of items cannot be shown in size available to the `TableView` without scrolling.

In this case all you'd need to do in the event handler would be adding a new item to the `TableView`, e.g. something like this

```
private void savecontacts(){
    contactsTable.getItems().add(new Contact(Name.getText(), PhoneNumber.getText(), Address.getText()));
    System.out.println("Save");
}
```

(`Contact` would be your item class in this case)